# freewall using ajax to append content and show [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem (noted above) with my code:

```
$(function() {
            var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
            wall.reset({
                selector: '.brick',
                animate: true,
                cellW: 160,
                cellH: 160,
                delay: 50,
                onResize: function() {
                    wall.fitWidth();
                }
            });
            wall.fitWidth();
            var content = $.ajax({
                    url:"contents/home.html",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType:"json"
                });
            var temp = '<div class="brick {size}">' + '<div class="covers">' + content + '</div>' + '</div>';
            var size = "size33 size32 size31 size23 size22 size21 size13 size12 size11".split(" ");
            $(".add-more").click(function() {
                var html = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                    html += temp.replace('{size}', size[size.length * Math.random() << 0])
                                /*.replace('{color}', colour[colour.length * Math.random() << 0])*/;
                }
                wall.appendBlock(html);
            });
        });
```

I tried to load the ajax content but it shows [object Object]. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should probably have a look at the [`$.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), because that's not how you're supposed to use it.

Comment: @KemalFadillah ohhh okay... so any solution for loading the content?

Comment: sure there's a solution, use ajax the way it is documented. WHat you are doing just won't work

Comment: @charlietfl what should I do? any reference can be share?

Comment: refrence has already been provided , read the documentation, or study some tutorials and start with a much simpler test page until you get some ajax understanding

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call helps.

Answer (score 0):

Write the logic to update DOM in a done function like this check out [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more information

```
$(function() {
    var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.brick',
        animate: true,
        cellW: 160,
        cellH: 160,
        delay: 50,
        onResize: function() {
            wall.fitWidth();
        }
    });
    wall.fitWidth();
    var content = $.ajax({
        url:"contents/home.html",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"json"
    }).done(function(data){
        var temp = '<div class="brick {size}">' + '<div class="covers">' + content + '</div>' + '</div>';
        var size = "size33 size32 size31 size23 size22 size21 size13 size12 size11".split(" ");
        $(".add-more").click(function() {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                html += temp.replace('{size}', size[size.length * Math.random() << 0])
                            /*.replace('{color}', colour[colour.length * Math.random() << 0])*/;
            }
            wall.appendBlock(html);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: *response data* should be concatenated, not the returned promise.